# Declaring instance variables outside of initialize

Tags: ruby, class

I'm trying to convert Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit and vice versa. As in the following, instance variable `@temperature` is defined in the methods `celsius=` and `fahrenheit=` respectively.

```
class Temperature
  def self.ctof(temp)
    (temp * 9 / 5.0) + 32
  end

  def self.ftoc(temp)
    (temp - 32) * (5 / 9.0)
  end

  def initialize(options)
    if options[:f]
      self.fahrenheit = options[:f]
    else
      self.celsius = options[:c]
    end
  end

  def fahrenheit=(temp)
    @temperature = self.class.ftoc(temp)
  end

  def celsius=(temp)
    @temperature = temp
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    self.class.ctof(@temperature)
  end

  def in_celsius
    @temperature
  end
end
```

It is confusing to me because I've never seen instance variables defined outside of the initialize method. I'm hoping someone can help me understand what is going on here.

Comment: What do you mean by methods `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit`? I can't find them in your code.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your conversion is prone to floating point inaccuracy: `Temperature.new(f: 10).in_fahrenheit` returns `9.999999999999996`

Comment: Instance variables aren't declared nor defined. They magically spring into existence when they are assigned, just like all other variables in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Temperature.new(c: 0)`, this will set the `celsius=` accessor, which sets the instance variable `@temperature` (which is meant to always be in Celsius) to `0`.

When you call `Temperature.new(f: 32)`, this will set the `fahrenheit=` accessor, which sets the instance variable `@temperature` to `Temperature.ftoc(32)`, or `0.0`.

Calling `in_celsius` simply returns `@temperature`, or `0` in the example.

Calling `in_fahrenheit` returns `Temperature.ctof(0)`, or `32.0`.

There is nothing magical about an instance variable being defined outside the constructor. The key point is that it is a variable that is available throughout the instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to set instance variables outside of `initialize`. This is exactly what setters do. You probably already know [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) – when calling `attr_accessor :foo`, it creates a getter `foo` and a setter `foo=` for the instance variable `@foo`, i.e. two methods equivalent to:

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
end
```

In your code, `in_celsius` and `celsius=` and just that: getters and setters for `@temperature`.

But your code does indeed look a bit convoluted. I think this is because `Temperature` has to handle both, Fahrenheit and Celsius. You can simplify it by providing separate classes for each temperature scale:

```
class Celsius
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_celsius
    self
  end

  def to_fahrenheit
    Fahrenheit.new((value * 9 / 5.0) + 32)
  end
end

class Fahrenheit
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_celsius
    Celsius.new((value - 32) * (5 / 9.0))
  end

  def to_fahrenheit
    self
  end
end
```

Now each class has a single instance variable `@value` which is being set within `initialize`.

```
temperature = Celsius.new(0)
#=> #<Celsius:0x007fb83d8b33a8 @value=0>

temperature.to_fahrenheit
#=> #<Fahrenheit:0x007fb83d8b3128 @value=32.0>
```